# JMeter - generate Dashboard report on specific times or steps (Load testing)

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I want to get a clear results when server is "fully loaded" with users operations and also a clear results when server start to get X login requests.

In JMeter I'm able to [generate Dashboard report](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/18816/how-to-generate-report-dashboard-in-jmeter) with given jtl or for all test.

In my load testing I have a test which doesn't stops (until shutdown manually)

In the first steps and minutes it ramp up all the users

In next steps it makes other actions on servers in a loop (while)

I want to generate 2 separated dashboard reports, one for ramping up/login users

and second for execution different actions on server (with full users)

Should I add 2 or more listeners in a controller for different steps and check its jtl after test is finish?

Can it be more flexible? I really wants to generate dashboard on demands or by time, for example, will include requests after 3 minutes the test start and until 15 minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create 2 reports by running web report generation with date interval.
Add to user.properties:

```
 jmeter.reportgenerator.date_format=yyyyMMddHHmmss

# Used to generate a report based on a date range
 # If jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format does not contain year
# then use 1970 as year

# Date range start date as per format declared in jmeter.reportgenerator.date_format 

jmeter.reportgenerator.start_date=
# Date range end date as per format declared in  jmeter.reportgenerator.date_format

jmeter.reportgenerator.end_date=
```

Comment: Yes you need to generate twice

Comment: for now you need to provide start and end dates.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [FilterResults Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FilterResultsTool/) which has `--start-offset` and `--end-offset` parameters to "slice" your result file into as many pieces as you need and use these split up results files for separate analysis.

Filter Results Tool can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

Comment: How to use labels ? (for include-labels)

Comment: Given the following command line: `--include-label-regex true --include-labels "someLabel(.*)"` only sample results which names start with `someLabel` will be included into generated filtered output. You have choice of either strict match or [Perl5-style regular expressions](https://www.pcre.org/) depending on `include-label-regex` setting value.